Create Task based on Opportunity Field Update
We're looking for a way to automate follow up tasks for sales as a part of their productivity goals. I created a new field called "Follow Up Date" on the oppty. When this field is populated with a date, a new task should be created for the oppty owner using that follow up date as the task due date.
The flow I created is not triggering and I can't seem to figure out why not. Does anyone have any tips?




Debug results: The triggering record didn’t meet the condition requirements, so the flow didn’t run.
Entry Conditions
Follow_Up_Date__c (Wed May 01 00:00:00 GMT 2024) Is null false
All conditions must be true (AND)
Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements.
Prior Entry Conditions
Follow_Up_Date__c (Fri Apr 26 00:00:00 GMT 2024) Is null false
All conditions must be true (AND)

are you debugging with an Opportunity that has Follow Up date non-null?

For your entry criteria the flow will only ever run once when an empty Follow_Up_Date__c field is populated with a value. The only other time it will run is if a user deletes the value in Follow_Up_Date__c, saves the record and then populates Follow_Up_Date__c with a value again.
I debugged the flow with an Opportunity that had an empty Follow_Up_Date__c and the flow triggered correctly:

I then debugged the flow with an Opportunity that had a prior value for Follow_Up_Date__c and just changed it. The flow did not trigger, which is also correct, as Follow_Up_Date__c did not change from being null to having a value:

If you only want one task to be created, then the current entry criteria is sufficient.
If you want a task to be created when the Follow_Up_Date__c field is populated and every time it is changed, I suggest you change your entry criteria to:

This will ensure that Follow_Up_Date__c is always provided and it will trigger every time Follow_Up_Date__c is changed.
Good luck!

Using Is Changed as the operator did the trick. Appreciate the assist!
